# How to Add web service reference into class library project .NET 4.0

Tags: .net, web-services, class-library

I want to add web service refernece into .NET class library project 4.0.

(previously web service was used into ASP.NET web application 2.0 as "add web service refernece").

I can't find "Add web reference" but there is an option to add "Add service reference".

Please suggest, both can be same or "Add service reference" is only for WCF service.

How can i add my web service reference into this class library ?

Thank You

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use that menu item - at the bottom of the dialog coming up there's another button for further options (German VS2010 translates to "Extended", English VS2010 says "Advanced"). In the dialog that comes up now, you can use the button "Add web service reference" in the "Compatibility" section.

Please note that configuration entries may be made to the `app.config` file of your DLL. As DLLs don't read the `app.config` file, you'll have to copy the settings to the `app.config` file of your application as described on SO multiple times.

Comment: I could not find - "Add web service refernece" while right click on class library project's reference. Do you mean, instead of adding reference, i have to just add app.config file into class library project and copy the configuraiton into that and it will works for making webmethod call ?

Comment: No. If you right-click on the "References" branch of your project, you can select "Add service reference". That's the menu item I'm talking about.

Comment: ok, but it looks, i can't find same methods directly.. looks like some wrapper created... do you know how i should have to use its mehtods. I mean, in web service, it was avaible direclty.. now i have to use through some wrapper ?

Comment: Is it resolved? I am facing same issue with my class library project.